# How to send firebase refreshToken ? React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, token

I am using firebase for the first time. (**React app)** I have 3 social Auth Provider for sign-in. Google, Facebook and Apple. Everything works great until here. But after 1 hour my token expires and I have to sign-out and sign-in again for refreshing my token. I saved the expiration time to my **localStorage** to check if token expires or not, if yes I invoke the **signOut()** function manually. But it doesn't solve the problem and not a good approach. **I can't find how to refreshToken in firebase.** And also, am I need to check expires again and send refreshToken or I have to refresh token on every time page refresh ?

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import auth from "../utils/Auth";

export const useSocialAuth = () => {
    
    const history = useHistory();
    const providerFunc = (socialProvider:any) => {
        const provider = socialProvider();
        provider
          .then((result: any) => {
            console.log(result)
            auth.login(() => {
              localStorage.setItem('exp', result.user._delegate.stsTokenManager.expirationTime)
              localStorage.setItem("userID", result.user.uid);
              localStorage.setItem("tocaToken", result.user.multiFactor.user.accessToken);
              history.push("/");
            });
          })
          .catch((err:any) => console.log(err));
    }

      return providerFunc;
  };
```

Comment: How are you getting the token at first place? Can you share the code? Are you asking about `Firebase ID Tokens` or the Tokens from those auth providers to access user info?

Comment: @Dharmaraj Shared.

Comment: If you are referring to Firebase ID Token, you can get it by `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()`. anytime

Comment: Allright, this is the another way to get token. I need to refreshToken when current token expires. Do you have any idea for this ? How can I handle this problem ?

Comment: In most cases you shouldn't have to deal with token management and expiraction yourself like that. Please edit your question to show how you sign the user into Firebase (so a call to `signInWith...`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the refresh token problem. All you guys need to add:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true)
```

When you make call from a browser `.getIdToken(true)` will automatically refresh your token. Make call like this:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/ forceRefresh / true)
.then(function(idToken) {

}).catch(function(error) {

});
```

More info: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken

Comment: can you pls share import statement for firebase

Comment: Do you do this before every http call?

Comment: Same question as Aaron above, and also will this trigger the onAuthStateChanged callback?